Middleware in Next.js Only Works for the First Request from Client-Side Navigation
I'm working with Next.js and facing an issue where middleware is not being triggered on subsequent navigations from a client-side route. Specifically, I'm using router.push in a React component with use client, but it seems that the middleware only performs its check on the first request and does not re-evaluate subsequent navigations. (NextJS 14)

Problem :
I have the following middleware configuration :
//app/user/signIn/page.js
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react'
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function SignIn() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const router = useRouter()

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      const result = await signIn('credentials', {
        redirect: false,
        email,
        password,
      })

      if (result.error) {
        setError('email or password is incorrect.')
      } else {
        router.push('/user/profile')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error)
      setError('An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.')
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='text-center'>
        <Link href="/user/profile" className="block mb-2">[Profile Menu]</Link>
        <Link href="/user/signIn" className="block mb-2">[Login Menu]</Link>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          className="bg-white p-6 rounded-md shadow-md"
        >
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
              id="email"
              type="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              required
              className="w-full border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 rounded"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input
              id="password"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              required
              className="w-full border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 rounded"
            />
          </div>
          {error && <p className="text-red-500 mb-4">{error}</p>}
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="w-full bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 rounded mb-4"
          >
            Sign In
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

//app/user/profile/page.js
'use client'

import { useSession, signOut } from 'next-auth/react'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Profile() {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession()
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)
    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (status === 'unauthenticated') {
            router.push('/user/signIn')
        }
    }, [status, router])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (session?.user?.id) {
            fetch(`/api/user/${session.user.id}`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => setUserData(data))
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching user data:', error)
                    Swal.fire('Error', 'Unable to fetch user data', 'error')
                })
        }
    }, [status, session])

    const handleSignOut = async () => {
        const result = await Swal.fire({
            title: 'Do you want to logout?',
            text: "Confirm logout.",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'OK',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancel'
        })

        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            signOut({ callbackUrl: '/user/signIn' })
        }
    }

    return (
        status === 'authenticated' &&
        session.user && (
            <>
                <div className="flex h-screen items-center justify-center">
                    <div className="bg-white p-6 rounded-md shadow-md">
                        <p>
                            Welcome, <b>{userData?.firstName} {userData?.lastName}!</b>
                        </p>
                        <p>Email: {userData?.email}</p>
                        <p>Role: {userData?.role.title}</p>
                        <button
                            onClick={handleSignOut}
                            className="w-full bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 rounded"
                        >
                            Logout
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    )
}

//middleware.js
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(request) {
  const user = await getToken({
    req: request,
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  });

  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/user/profile') && !user) {
    const signInUrl = new URL('/user/signIn', request.url);
    return NextResponse.redirect(signInUrl);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

//app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email', placeholder: 'john@doe.com' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!credentials) return null
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: { email: credentials.email },
        })

        if (
          user &&
          (await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password))
        ) {
          return {
            id: user.id,
            firstName: user.firstName,
            lastName: user.lastName,
            email: user.email,
            roleId: user.roleId
          }
        } else {
          throw new Error('Invalid email or password')
        }
      },
    })
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id
        token.roleId = user.roleId
      }
      return token
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.id
        session.user.roleId = token.roleId
      }
      return session
    }
  },
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }

Issue:

When I navigate to /user/profile after signing in, the middleware performs the redirection as expected if there is no token.
However, when I navigate to /user/profile again from the client-side using router.push, the middleware does not re-check or perform the redirection again.

Question:
Is this behavior expected with Next.js middleware? Why does the middleware only trigger on the first request and not on subsequent navigations from the client-side? How can I ensure that the middleware runs and performs checks on every request, even those triggered by router.push from a client-side component?
Additional Information:

I'm using Next.js with NextAuth for authentication.
My goal is to make sure that every time a user tries to access /user/profile, the middleware checks for a token and redirects to the sign-in page if the token is missing.


I think the problem is with the next middleware cache. It doesn't check again after the last login when there is a token, so you need to add a check
response.headers.set("x-middleware-cache", "no-cache");

So your middleware needs to be changed like this.
//middleware.js
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(request) {
  const user = await getToken({
    req: request,
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  });

  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/user/profile') && !user) {
    const response = NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/user/signIn", request.url));
    response.headers.set("x-middleware-cache", "no-cache");
    return response;
  }

  const response = NextResponse.next();
  response.headers.set("x-middleware-cache", "no-cache");
  return response;
}

